# Finding the maximum value in a Pandas column for multiple rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Please, help me with the following example,
I have `DataFrame`:

```
data ={'Сlient':['1', '2', '3', '3', '3', '4'], \
       'date1':['2019-11-07', '2019-11-08', '2019-11-08', '2019-11-08', '2019-11-08', '2019-11-11'], \
       'date2':['2019-11-01', '2019-11-02', '2019-11-06', '2019-11-07', '2019-11-10', '2019-11-15']  } 
df =pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to create a column with a date, which from the group of `date2` for each client selects the maximum value, and it should be less than the value of `date1` for this client.

For example for client 3, I need to get `2019-11-07`.

Can this be done with Lambda function?

Comment: Can you add expected output? Row for `Cliant=4` is removed?

Comment: Looks like it is the first character (`ord(df.columns[0][0]) == ord('C')` prints False). Interesting.

Comment: Apparently it is `Cyrillic Capital Letter Es`. TIL.

Comment: @KentShikama I guess `df.columns[0]` is `date1` when you convert it to DataFrame.

Comment: @Sarques No it is "Client". This is a unicode character issue. See https://www.codetable.net/decimal/1057

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for filter out rows less like `date1` values and then get index values by maximum `date2` values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and seelct by `loc`:

```
df[['date1','date2']] = df[['date1','date2']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df1 = df.loc[df[df['date2'].lt(df['date1'])].groupby('Сlient')['date2'].idxmax()]
print (df1)
  Сlient      date1      date2
0      1 2019-11-07 2019-11-01
1      2 2019-11-08 2019-11-02
3      3 2019-11-08 2019-11-07
```

Another solution with filtering by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and remove duplicated by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = (df.query('date2 < date1')
         .sort_values(['Сlient','date2'], ascending=[True, False])
         .drop_duplicates('Сlient'))
print (df1)
  Сlient      date1      date2
0      1 2019-11-07 2019-11-01
1      2 2019-11-08 2019-11-02
3      3 2019-11-08 2019-11-07
```

EDIT:

Then last  step is use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['date2'] = df['Сlient'].map(df1.set_index('Сlient')['date2'])
print (df)
  Сlient      date1      date2
0      1 2019-11-07 2019-11-01
1      2 2019-11-08 2019-11-02
2      3 2019-11-08 2019-11-07
3      3 2019-11-08 2019-11-07
4      3 2019-11-08 2019-11-07
5      4 2019-11-11        NaT
```

Comment: the output should be: 'date2': ['2019-11-01', '2019-11-02', '2019-11-07', '2019-11-07', '2019-11-07', NaN']